# Jquery Chosen: populate Multiple Select with Tab button

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

here is the example page and it has Multiple Select input.

When I start typing, it highlights options. On this moment, when I press Tab button focus moves on other input and leaves previous input empty. I want to add new option when user start typing, for example, user typed 'af', 'Afganistan'is highlighted, user press tab button and Afganistan must be added.

I tried to handle tab keypress, and do `$(optionid).click()` to simulate mouse or enter select, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried everything I could think of when it comes to adding event handlers on top of Chosen but to no avail. I've tried catching tab press and simulate clicks on the highlighted item and simulating pressing Enter on the input field but to no avail.

I think however that if you are willing to hack Chosen, only a few very minor changes are needed.

First change:

```
Chosen.prototype.keydown_checker = function(evt) {
    ...
    //Replace the existing "case 9:" with this:
    case 9: //tab
        if(!this.is_multiple){
            if (this.results_showing && !this.is_multiple) {
                this.result_select(evt);
            }
            this.mouse_on_container = false;          
        }
        else {
            evt.preventDefault();
        }
        break;
    ...
}
```

Second change:

```
AbstractChosen.prototype.keyup_checker = function(evt) {
    ...
    case 9: //Simply add this above "case 13:" and remove "case 9:" from further down the switch statement
    case 13: //Enter
    ...
}
```

Edit: I have now tested this using their bundled example page and it seems to be working. as intended.

Comment: In version 1.5 I only needed to change ```case 9:
          if (this.results_showing) {
            this.result_select(evt);
          }
          this.mouse_on_container = false;
          break;```

Answer (score 0):

i've done some changes, and get what i want. thx, Peter Herdenborg!

```
AbstractChosen.prototype.keyup_checker = function (evt) { ...
    ... 
    case 9:
        if (this.search_field.val().length != 0) {
              if (this.results_showing) return this.result_select(evt);
        }
        break;
    case 13:
    ...
```

and second

```
Chosen.prototype.keydown_checker = function (evt) {
      case 9:
          if (!this.is_multiple) {
              if (this.results_showing && !this.is_multiple) {
                        this.result_select(evt);
                    }
              this.mouse_on_container = false;
          }
          else {
             if (this.search_field.val().length != 0) evt.preventDefault();
         }
         break;
```